# Why slider start at wrong place?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I'm trying to pass the slider value to span and dynamically change it. It works fine, but when i start page, the slider button displaced on the wrong value. How can I fix that?
This is my HTML

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Slider Control</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">

            <label for="points">Points:</label>
            <input type="range" data-highlight="true"  data-bind="attr: {'id': id, 'min': min, 'max': max}, value: value, valueUpdate: 'input'" />
            Net: <span data-bind="text: value"></span>
    </div>
```

This is [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6L1xhh06/)

**EDIT**

This is example of slider, where slider starts on its place.
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bd00oa6t/)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like jQuery mobile initializes the slider *before* knockout sets its value.

**Quick and dirty solution: (not recommended)** manually trigger an update after applying bindings.

```
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
$("input").trigger("change");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/avk9dyw4/

**Real solution**: apply bindings *before* jquery mobile initializes or create a custom binding handler that takes care of the order of initializing widgets and setting attributes.

Comment: _apply bindings before jquery mobile initializes_ you mean something like that

Comment: `<input data-bind="attr: {'id': id, 'min': min, 'max': max}, value: value, valueUpdate: 'input'" type="range" data-highlight="true" />`

Comment: It's not about the order of the attributes, but about the order in which jQuery and knockout do their processing of the DOM. jQuery mobile uses the `min`, `max` and `value` attributes to render a custom control. knockout sets these attributes when you call `applyBindings`. So when jQuery mobile creates the UI *before* knockout has had the chance to set the attributes, it cannot yet know the value and renders a default widget.